# Add contact to Exchange public folder with C# or PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

How do I add a contact to an Exchange Server 2010 public folder using C# or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Microsoft Exchange Web Services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

Comment: it has a Contact class that you can use to update contacts.  It may have a small learning curve, but it works